# Realm и JSON в swift (перевод с англ.)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm, realm-database

(Перевод с англ.) Я пытаюсь получить title и description с JSON ресурса из базы данных REALM. Могу получить title без проблем, но не могу получить description, потому что это зарезервированное имя в SWIFT, поэтому я пробовал ObjectMapper. И всё равно, не могу получить description... Код такой...

Ещё у меня есть другая проблема. Каким образом мне записать исходный (source) объект из NewRealmSourceLib в объект NewRealmLib. Мой способ не работает!

```
{
    "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/mazoe-ford/6525834, http://www.abc.net.au/news/dom--vukovic/7637226",
    "title": "Jury takes just 32 minutes to convict two men over Daley's violent death",
    "description": "Two men are found guilty over the death of Lynette Daley, whose naked body was found bruised and bloodied after a boozy 2011 camping trip to a remote beach in northern NSW.",
    "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-09-06/lynette-daley-trial-delivers-guilty-verdicts/8878848",
    "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/7392268-1x1-700x700.jpg",
    "publishedAt": "2017-09-06T09:14:02Z"
    },


class NewRealmLib : Object, Mappable {

        dynamic var title: String = ""
        dynamic var descript: String = ""

        var source: NewRealmSourceLib?

        required convenience init?(map: Map) {
            self.init()
        }

        func mapping(map: Map) {
            descript <- map["description"]
            title <- map["title"]

        }

        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "title"
        }
    }
    class NewRealmSourceLib: Object {
        dynamic var source: String = ""
        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "source"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете получить title и description используя `protocol Decodable` и `JSONDecoder()` в **Swift 4**. Код приведён ниже. Зарезервированные слова в Swift можно использовать как свои идентификаторы, заключив их в символы backticks (``` `` ```).

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "author": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/mazoe-ford/6525834, http://www.abc.net.au/news/dom--vukovic/7637226",
    "title": "Jury takes just 32 minutes to convict two men over Daley's violent death",
    "description": "Two men are found guilty over the death of Lynette Daley, whose naked body was found bruised and bloodied after a boozy 2011 camping trip to a remote beach in northern NSW.",
    "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-09-06/lynette-daley-trial-delivers-guilty-verdicts/8878848",
    "urlToImage": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/7392268-1x1-700x700.jpg",
    "publishedAt": "2017-09-06T09:14:02Z"
}
"""
```

Декларация класса, соответствующего протоколу Decodable:

```
class NewRealmLib : Decodable {
    var author : String
    var title : String
    var description : String
    var url : URL
    var urlToImage : URL
    var publishedAt : String
}
```

Вариант использования данных JSON с Decodable–классом и декодером JSONDecoder():

```
func __test_so_715056() {
    print("[TEST]: \(#function)")
    let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let lib = try! decoder.decode(NewRealmLib.self, from:data!)
    let `description` = lib.description // Используем backticks
    print(lib.title)
    print(`description`)
    print("[/TEST]")
}
```

Результат получения title и description будет таким.

```
[TEST]: __test_so_715056()
Jury takes just 32 minutes to convict two men over Daley's violent death
Two men are found guilty over the death of Lynette Daley, whose naked body was found bruised and bloodied after a boozy 2011 camping trip to a remote beach in northern NSW.
[/TEST]
```